# redirect time too high! from non-www domain to www.domain

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I have setup canonical redirects in my nginx config file, however it takes 7sec to redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com (from firebug)
this is my chunk of config:

```
server_name example.com
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
```

Any way to improve this? where should I look into?

UPDATE:

I checked again:
example.com (status 301 moved permanently time 10ms, initiator:others) www.example.com (status 302 Found initiator: example.com time:7sec) 
I checked further I have waiting TTFB 6.58 sec. 
Is it rather slow backend response?

Comment: Well, you have the firebug output. What part of the redirect took so long?

Comment: Please edit those details into your question.

Comment: please see edit update

Comment: What's firebug say about this 301 service, also running nginx, http://www.jacobdevans.com/anycast-301/